# Should I capitalize "l" if I put log2 at beginning of a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

For example, which of the following is correct?

A:

> log<sub>2</sub> fold change of A is larger than that of B.

B:

> Log<sub>2</sub> fold change of A is larger than that of B.

I was thinking "log<sub>2</sub>" is a function name and don't need to be capitalized.

Comment: Are you using a specific style guide?

Comment: @Laurel, no. Actually I do know whether there are some style guides about this. Would you suggest one for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using any style guide, you have freedom (just be consistent). I would avoid starting a sentence with log because it's a little weird. Instead, use an apposition:

> A good general rule is: never start a sentence with a symbol. If you insist on starting the sentence with a mention of the thing the symbol denotes, put the appropriate word in apposition, thus: “The set X belongs to the class C, . . . ”.
>   <sub>[How to write Mathematics](http://www2.math.uu.se/~takis/ETC/Halmos_howToWriteMath.pdf)</sub>

If you're writing a label (as you say you're doing in one comment), I wouldn't capitalize it. The Chicago Manual of Style recommends lowercase in this situation:

> Labels, the descriptive items within a chart, are normally lowercased (with the exception of proper nouns or other terms that would be capitalized in running text); if phrases, they may be capitalized sentence-style.

---

You will rarely find log [capitalized](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9901101.pdf), but it is occasionally done.

Comment: Well explained. I am revising a scientific article, I think I should stick to the style guide like the one mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the problem entirely by starting the sentence with another word, i.e., by writing "The log2 fold change of A is larger than that of B."

Comment: I usually do it as you suggested. But sometimes it workaround is not allowed, for example, when need to put it as x-axis label of a figure.